# Edges on arc, using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am experimenting with drawing using javascript and the canvas element..my goal now is to draw a circle and gradually increase the opacity; I have this code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrVvOQ

Which seems to work, but the circle has rough edges; I found I need to clear the canvas each time the frame is redrawn, but the attempts I have made have not quite worked...any suggestions on how to?

```
window.onload = function draw(){
       var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
       if (frame1.getContext){
         var ctx = frame1.getContext('2d');
         var centerX = frame1.width / 2;
         var centerY = frame1.height / 2;

         var radius = 50;


         var alpha = 1.0;

           /*call function over and over */
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


           var rendergreen = function()
{

              var opacityValue = 0;

                opacityValue += 0.03;
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(68,107,62, ' + opacityValue + ')';
                animate();
              ctx.arc(50, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
              ctx.clip();
              ctx.fill();

              ctx.closePath;


              function animate() {


                if (opacityValue < 1) {
                         opacityValue += 0.3;


                } else {
                     opacityValue = 1;


                }


}

            requestAnimationFrame(rendergreen);


       }
           rendergreen();


       }
}
```

Comment: place `ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)` at top of your drawing function. Also, you should move your opacity variable out of the render scope, or it will always be equal to `0.05`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the circle has "rough edges". That's pixellation and is inherent in using `canvas` to draw, which is a bit-mapped style of graphics. That means that you essentially can't get higher resolution than a single pixel. Contrast that with `svg` which is vector-based. An `svg` image can be magnified a thousand times and still have a smooth edge. I've shown an svg circle next to the canvas circle so that you can see the difference. It becomes much more apparent if you zoom in with your browser. There are pro's and con's to using canvas vs svg, too much to go into here, but it's worth looking into if you're really concerned.

In terms of changing the opacity of the circle, you've got several problems with your approach. With the way you've written it, you're actually not changing the opacity. Instead, you're drawing the same very transparent circle many times over top of each other so that by the end it looks opaque, giving the impression that you are gradually increasing the transparency of a single circle. Notice that you're setting your opacity to zero in each drawing iteration, then incrementing it to 0.05 *(note that there are differences in the code in your question versus in the codepen that you linked to...I'm referring to the codepen version)*, then drawing it (so it will always be drawn at opacity 0.05), then further changing the value of the variable `opacityValue` which is never used in the drawing. The example below shows a relatively simple example of what I think you were trying to achieve. Note that I've deliberately made the 'clearRect' too small so that you can see how not clearing the canvas each time allows semi-transparent drawings to "pile up". This also allows you to see that the blockiness gets worse if you overlay many semi-transparent images. e.g. Compare the left and right sides of the canvas circle. The part of the circle that is cleared every time ends up looking smoother because of anti-aliasing, but the overlaid images have the smoothing effects of anti-aliasing effectively destroyed.

```js
window.onload = function draw() {
  var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
  if (frame1.getContext) {
    var ctx = frame1.getContext('2d');
    var opacityValue = 0;
    var render = function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 80, 80); // deliberately set too small
      ctx.beginPath();
      opacityValue += 0.01;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(68,107,62, ' + opacityValue + ')';
      ctx.arc(60, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath;
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    render();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="frame1" width="120" height="120"></canvas>
<svg width="120" height="120">
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="#446B3E"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: So your last sentence contradicts the first one... canvas drawing operations are vectors just like svg and svg will be rendered on a pixel base too, it's just that browsers will re-render the svg at each resize (you can do exactly the same with canvas and its transform matrix).

Comment: Yes, the browsers must eventually re-render everything, including svg, eventually onto the physical medium that they have...pixels. And, yes, the canvas instructions also include vector-based ideas. However, I've always understood one of the main differences between canvas and svg as a difference between bit-mapped versus vector-based graphics. Do I have a factual mistake in my answer (which I would be more than happy to correct once I understand) or are you just providing helpful background information for other readers?

Comment: In terms of the first and last sentences contradicting each other...I would say that perhaps I didn't choose the best words (so I take your point there) but I believe the concepts still hold. The canvas circle always has "blocky" edges. With a single shape, those "blocks" are different shades due to anti-aliasing, so an un-zoomed shape might look "smooth" at first glance. However, if you zoom in, you'll still see the "blocks" when comparing it to an svg shape. It's just that when you overlay many "blocky" shapes the shading of all the "blocks" goes to maximum, emphasizing the "blocky-ness".

Comment: Thanks! I knew the issue was redrawing, your approach helps; there is a lack of good documentation on both canvas and SVG...thanks for your help!

Comment: If I wanted multiple circles...would I use the same frame?

Comment: When you say "frame" I assume you mean enclosing `<canvas>` element. If so, then the simple answer, in most cases, is: Yes, use a single `<canvas>` element to draw as many different shapes as you need within a rectangular area. The only reason I used two different elements was because the two circles I showed are two fundamentally different things, one drawn using a `<canvas>` element and the other using an `<svg>` element.